# ZMQ Multithread C client

Tags: c, multithreading, zeromq

I want C example for Multithreaded `zmq` client, I am already using Multithreaded server, but I have requirements to make each client send requests from multithreads not from a single thread.

I had a look at:

http://zguide.zeromq.org/c:asyncsrv
https://github.com/booksbyus/zguide/blob/master/examples/C/

but I didn't see client example that uses multithreads of `ZMQ_DEALER` socket talking to Multithreaded server ( a `ZMQ_ROUTER` socket )

So I am looking for `DEALER` and `ROUTER` pattern. I want the client ( the `DEALER` ) to be multithreaded:

- if I follow same analogy of multi-threaded server example, I need a proxy that binds multiple dealers threads, correct?

or

- is using a **`pthread_create`** enough?

Currently my client is similar to hello world C:

```
zctx_t ctx = zctx_new ();
void *client = zsocket_new (ctx, ZMQ_REQ);
assert (client);
zsocket_connect (client, config.SERVER_ENDPOINT);

// SKIPPED: I get the data (hm->body.p) to be send through zmq...

// We send a request, then we work to get a reply

zstr_sendf(client, "%.*s", (int) hm->body.len,hm->body.p);

char *reply = zstr_recv (client);
if (  reply ) {
      zsys_info ("server replied (%s)", reply);
      free (reply);
}
```

Please help me make my C client to be a Multithreaded `zmq` client.

**Update 1 (More details):**

1. I have a 3rd party application (let's call it **`3pa`** ) that I need to integrate with. The `3pa` sends on average ~ 4 **`HTTP POST`** requests per second ( each request's size ~ 60 KB ) to an HTTP Listener ( I am using mongoose ).
2. `3pa` ONLY sends a next `HTTP POST` after it receives a `"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"` "reply" **OR** after a timeout for the sent request. So `3pa` seems to be single threaded.
3. In case I am not able to respond with **`200 OK`** quickly, the `3pa` will keep queuing in Memory, until it crashes.
4. When I receive a request from `3pa`, I need to send it over a 3G-mobile-packet network, to the backend server., using ZMQ. Due to the 3G-mobile-packet network latency and bandwidth, each request requires about 1-3 seconds to be sent, and about 1-3 seconds for a ZMQ replay `new ZFrame("OK")` to be initiated, transported and delivered (received on the `3pa` side).

So, if we make the elementary calculus, `3pa` queue capacity will be filled up so fast due to the 3G-mobile-packet network performance.

Comment: What do you translate the being "multi-threaded" into? ZeroMQ Scaleable Formal Communication Patterns are very powerfull on their own. For particular performance-related reasons, all services are based on the common grounds of a `Context( number_of_IO_threads )` instance, where some additional low level hacks allow one to map some sockets for being handled with a given CPU/core affinity mapping. That makes sense for an advanced `zmq` data-pumps' performance tuning. Could you translate your multithreading requirements into a plain english specification of must-have + nice-to-have properties?

Comment: I will update the question to give good plain English specs

Comment: @user3666197 check the update, do you want more plain English details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the few details provided in the OP/Update 1,
let's focus on the root cause of the problem,
before speaking about an idea of increasing the number of threads.

---

### What indeed matters?

Given the **`3pa`** has been introduced as a <kbd>BlackBox</kbd>, with an experienced blocking-design ( indicated by a waiting forever, till a delivery of **`200 OK`**, with an escape on a timeout event )
**the best first step** would be to operate that `3pa` as-is, but rather hosted/colocated on some better NIX-peering/colocation centre, than on a current "peripheral" last-mile part of the latency-expensive 3G-mobile-packet radio access network, that would both avoid/prevent a capacity-driven DoS-introduced packet re-transmits in case any prioritised call-traffic preempts 3G-channels and congests the RAN and would absolutely reduce the costs of the round-trip latency, currently paid at the said levels somewhere above 2~6+ seconds.

The next step possible, if the `3pa` relocation to a NIX-proximity on it's own were not enough to save the game, would be to create o single purpose http-proxy, that would receive those 60KB+ http-requests ( that would be than relayed to a due target ) and that would immediately inject **`200 OK`** response downstream, to the hands of `3pa`, so as to unlock it from it's internal blocking-loop and allowing it to send another de-queued **`HTTP POST`**.

Dirty? Yes and no. It solves the weaknesses of a poor `3pa` design and allows to operate it in given circumstances.

---

### The last note - rather avoid **`REQ/REP`** patterns in real scenarios.

Whereas the ZeroMQ Scaleable Formal Communication Patterns building blocks are smart examples of multi-party communication schemes, do not expect them to be immune to LoS, lost messages and other real-world issues. **`REQ/REP`** pattern is able to deadlock itself in a de-railed internal FSA-state, from which there are no ( literally Zero ) tools to save / resuscitate the inter-twinned FSA-state machines from a unsalvageable mutually deadlocked state.

Use some other Scaleable Formal Communication Patterns in such design and be ready to provide additional means of signalling for a potential need to salvage states, when something goes wrong. ZeroMQ has a lot of tools for doing that smarter, than just relying on a single trivial archetype, close ones eyes and belive in a fiction that everything will work error-free forever ( that is not the reality we live our lives in, right :o) ).

[image: Mixed SIG & TRANSPORT layers]

Real-world clients operate many zmq-socket instances, some for signalling, some for transport-services, some for remote access to a client's internal CLI interface, some other for a distributed log-collector, some for self-diagnostics and hosting-system health-checks. Simple, principally non-blocking designed clients may contain some small thousands of SLOCs, so forget to expect any such solution to consist of just a copy of a few SLOCs from a library wiki-pages or from some sparkling blog posts.

> One might also like to **[read other ZeroMQ posts,](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D)** with also a link to the fabulous Pieter HINTJENS' **book**, that has been my **must-read** recommendation for those interested since I started to love the ZeroMQ way of thinking and design priorities. Worth the time and efforts, believe me or not, distributed processing has other, more important rules, than just asking for more threads for otherwise poor and un-feasible design.
> Being able to change a poor design into a better one, one can still operate a single-threaded, well designed, application that can move xKB-messages and keep the end-to-end latencies under a few tens of milliseconds, even with a remote server doing a complex AI/ML-processing of the "fat"-data payloads.
> Worth a try, isn't it?

Comment: thank you a lot, even though many terms used I had no idea about! I always try to implement simple yet fully functioning solution. on LAN environment and 4G network, I had no issue at all, but since I found that single ZMQ thread client didn't utilize the full bandwidth of 3G network, I thought that multi-threads might boost/increase bandwidth usage, I worry that implementation might render clients and server machines inaccessible, but it worth a try, isn't it?

Comment: **ITU has not provided a clear definition of the data rate** users can expect from 3G. Users sold 3G service can't point to such a standard & claim the rates it specifies were not met. While in commentary (cit.:) "it is expected that IMT-2000 will provide higher transmission rates: a minimum data rate of 2 Mbit/s for stationary or walking users, and 384 kbit/s in a moving vehicle," the ITU does not actually clearly specify minimum required rates, nor required average rates, nor what modes of the I/F qualify as 3G, so various, **a lot different in reality, *data rates*** are being sold as '3G'

Comment: In market implementation, **theoretical 3G downlink data speeds** defined by telecom service providers vary depending on the underlying technology deployed; up to 384kbit/s for WCDMA, up to 7.2Mbit/sec for HSPA and a theoretical maximum of 21.6 Mbit/s for HSPA+

Comment: The worst nail into the coffin is the managed prioritisation of traffic-flows in the realms of the limitted transport-capacity areas (the **last mile** (always in dense populated areas + always in highly dynamic cells ( airport and railway coverage cells, peaking on block arrivals of the whole herd of mobile terminals, highway with frequent fast moving mobile terminal handovers etc)+ **trunking capacities in the transport network grooming** ).Phone calls (VOICE) being always prioritised & DATA is not, assuming the higher OSI-model layers **can "solve" lost packets+jitter+timeouts (hopefully)**

Comment: Thank you again, I am wondering about the style you are using in expressing your thoughts! I feel you are more of theoretical programmer (an analogy to theoretical physicist). I found this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/813548/ZeroMQ-sharp-Sending-From-Multiple-Sockets which seems similar to what I was looking for. I know that finding what I was looking for in this question might not solve the problem, but sometimes its faster to try simple change rather than decoding your answer. I hope to hear your response as I don't mean to offend you by any mean.

Comment: After more than 30 years of programming, this is the first salutation of **"Theoretical Programmer"**. Coding does not create an understanding. One may try a lot of things, but proper know-how of how things indeed work under the hood allows one to design smart systems. Threading does not help one with poor design, the less with fighting against superposition of principally immense jitter + almost timeout-killing latency in 3G-mobile packet network. Also one shall remember, that **ZeroMQ strongly discourages from sharing sockets among threads** ( explicitly warns about not being thread-safe )